# javascript service dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any difference on these controllers(firstController.js & secondController.js), 
both are working fine. I am following the first one, sometimes I am getting the following error log. If I refresh the page then error won't occur

"Error : MyService.login is not a function"

**firstController.js**

```
.controller('MyController',function($scope,MyService){
    MyService.login($scope.credential).$promise.then(function(data){

    })
});
```

**secondController.js**

```
.controller('MyController',['$scope','MyService',function($scope,MyService){
    MyService.login($scope.credential).$promise.then(function(data){

    })
}]);
```

**MyService.js**

```
.factory('MyService', function($resource) {
    return $resource("/access/login", {}, {
        login : {method : 'POST'}
    });
```

})

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Hey guys I made a spelling mistake, Question updated. please check

Answer (score 1):

`.controller('MyController',function($scope,MySerice){`

should be

`.controller('MyController',function($scope,MyService){`

you forgot a 'v'

Comment: I create a sample code snippet to get it clarified. that is not a exact code.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo in

```
.controller('MyController',function($scope,MySerice){
```

There should be `$scope.MyService`

Answer (score 1):

"Error : **MySerice**.login is not a function"

You probably forgot the letter '**v**' in '**MyService**'.

**firstController.js** should look like this:

```
.controller('MyController',function($scope,MyService){
   MyService.login($scope.credential).$promise.then(function(data){

    })
});
```

BTW, sometimes error tells you a lot :)